# why not pass function arguments in Object or Associative Array?

Tags: javascript

I have a question: why not pass function arguments in Associative Array? Or Object? Is it a bad habit?

Instead of

```
function (a, b, c) { return a }
```

Why not

```
function (array) { return array.a }
```

?

Reason:

1. When we call this function, we pass the args in wrong order, it won’t break.
2. When the function is updated and the required args is changed (eg we add “d” as args), we don’t need to change the function args declaration

I’m new to programming, sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: You can very well pass arguments as an array or object. Not a bad practice at all.

Comment: Note that your `Arr` is not an array, but an object - precise variable names are important. Also consider destructuring the argument immediately, if it's an object.

Comment: Whatever is clearer for the situation at hand: for me, `function getFullName(firstName, lastName)...` has a clearer purpose that `function getFullName(nameArray)...`, but yes, you could equally argue that the second form allows for, say, a middle initial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of of the advantages of having multiple primitive type arguments rather than an object or an associative array is that it's arguably easier to read as long as there aren't too many arguments. It may also be easier to reuse in cases where you don't want to force the caller to package the arguments into an object beforehand.

It's certainly not bad practice to pass objects or arrays as parameters. There are cases where it is almost definitely the best option.

You should probably pass an object with your arguments if you have a large number of parameters. This makes things easier to read and easier to modify in the future. If you do this, it would probably be best to deconstruct your object at the beginning of the function definition like so:

```
function doStuff (parameterObject) {
  const { a, b, c } = parameterObject;
  // ...
}
```

When there isn't a max number of parameters for a function, it's a good idea to pass all your arguments into an array and then process that in your function.

There's no set rule on what to pass to functions, but the most important thing is to be smart about it.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about this elegant pattern - [Receive an object, return an object (RORO)](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/elegant-patterns-in-modern-javascript-roro-be01e7669cbd?gi=76860b20a287)
You may fall in love with it.